# How to update referenced key id to null in one to one doctrine

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, doctrine, cascade, one-to-one

I am running in this issue. Whenever I delete a company entity, the contact entity which has company's id as reference key throws an error.

> Company for IDs ID(29) was not found

I have this:

```
Contacts Table
ID, Name, Company_ID

Companies Table
ID, Name
```

And I have these relationships in their entities.

```
Contact.php
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Company", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Company_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
 */
private $company;

Company.php
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Contact", mappedBy="company")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ID", referencedColumnName="Company_ID")
 */
private $contacts;
```

I'm fairly new to doctrine. But when I delete a company of ID `1` then all the contacts with Company_ID = 1 should become null. Is this something that doctrine could handle or I MUST write manual code for it.

Comment: Add `orphanRemoval=true` to the relation (mind! Read [these docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal)!) and set `cascade` to `"persist", "remove"`. Mind, this is based on the assumption that a `Contact` is "owned" by a `Company` and cannot stand alone. (If a `Contact` **_can_** stand alone, you might want to change the relation to Uni-directional ManyToMany with a JoinTable)

Comment: Yeah, Contact can stand alone. ManyToMany wouldn't suit. Contact can have only one company.

Comment: In that case you need a OneToMany Uni-directional, which comes to a ManyToMany with JoinTable in the annotation, see: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table